# Win32 API named pipe, All pipe instances are busy

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to write in a named pipe and read back the same thing. Consider the following code snippet (the error handling is stripped for brevity):

```
const char * pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\pipe";
const char * buffWrite = "SOME TEXT";
unsigned buffLength = strlen(buffWrite);
char buffRead[1024];
DWORD nWritten, nRead;

HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName,
PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 1024, 1024, 0, 0);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pipeName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
WriteFile(hFile, buffWrite, buffLength, &nWritten, 0);
CloseHandle(hFile);
//the next line fails with >>All pipe instances are busy.<<
hFile = CreateFile(pipeName, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
ReadFile(hFile, buffRead, buffLength, &nRead, 0);
...
```

However when I try reopen the pipe for reading the CreateFile call fails with "All pipes are busy."

What am I missing here?

**EDIT.**
Peeking works fine, i.e.

```
DWORD nRead, nTotal, nLeft;
PeekNamedPipe(hPipe, buffRead, buffLength, &nRead, &nTotal, &nLeft);
```

returns the written data correctly.

**REMARK.**
This is a proof of concept for something larger. No new threads and processes will be involved.

Comment: That error code tells you that somebody else is already reading from the pipe.  There can be only one reader, having more than one would just create chaos when each reader gets a random bit of the data.  Nothing in your snippet makes it obvious what other code might be reading.  But clearly it is buggy code.

Comment: Who is that somebody else?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use named pipe as some kind of buffer - client connects to it, puts some data, then disconnects, after that other client connects and retrieves this data. This is invalid approach, named pipe is just that - a *pipe*, it has two sides - *server side* and *client side*, server and client could communicate through it. Usual pipe usage scenario:

1. Server creates named pipe using `CreateNamedPipe` function;
2. Server begin waiting for the client connections using `ConnectNamedPipe` method;
3. Client creates its side of the pipe using `CreateFile` API call;
4. Server and client communicate using `ReadFile/WriteFile`;
5. Pipe is closed with `DisconnectNamedPipe` and could be reactivated again with `ConnectNamedPipe`.

You could see complete example in the MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So is reading and writing a given named pipe from the same thread forbidden? Could you point me to a place where this is explicitly stated?

Comment: No it is not forbidden. But if you write some data using your `hFile` pipe handle, you must read it using `hPipe`. In your example you close connection after writing data so it is lost.

Comment: Also it is worth pointing out that named pipes are mechanism for the interprocess communication. Using them in the single thread is pointless.

Comment: @Ari0nnh. No, it's not lost after closing hFile. I did a PeekNamedPipe right after closing hFile, and the string was in there.

Comment: Closing the client end of a pipe doesn't discard the data, that only happens when the server end is closed or disconnected.

Comment: Yes of course, server still could get pipe data after client disconnects. What I mean, that other client, who somehow connects to this pipe could not retrieve this data, like in question's code fragment.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're getting that specific error code is that you only created one instance of the named pipe, and you've already used it.  (You can create a new instance by calling `CreateNamedPipe` a second time, or you can reuse an existing instance by calling `DisconnectNamedPipe`.)

However, based on your commentary, I believe you want the call to ReadFile to retrieve the data written by the call to WriteFile, i.e., you want the same instance of the pipe, not a new one.

To do that, do not open a new handle.  Use the existing handle, `hPipe`.

(Note that each pipe instance has two ends; a server end and a client end.  The handle from CreateNamedPipe is always to the server end, and the handle from CreateFile is always to the client end.  Data written to the server end can only be read from the client end, and vice-versa.)

Answer (score 0):

It is because both extremities of the pipe have allready be opened (*)...

First was opened with the CreatePipe call, the other was with the first CreateFile call. You should not try to open one time more the pipe, but simply read from the hPipe HANDLE :

```
const char * pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\pipe";
const char * buffWrite = "SOME TEXT";
unsigned buffLength = strlen(buffWrite);
char buffRead[1024];
DWORD nWritten, nRead;

HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName,
PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 1024, 1024, 0, 0);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pipeName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
WriteFile(hFile, buffWrite, buffLength, &nWritten, 0);
CloseHandle(hFile);

ReadFile(hPipe, buffRead, buffLength, &nRead, 0); // nRead=9, buffRead="SOME TEXT"
...
```

(*) You did specify `PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES` for the `nMaxInstances` parameter in `CreateNamedPipe` call, but as you never called `ConnectNamedPipe` to create other endpoints, only one `CreateFile` was allowed.